# Is it possible to call PopUpMenuButton inside a button?

Tags: flutter

I want to create PopUpMenuButton like picture below.

[image]

Is it possible to create PopUpMenuButton inside a button? Because I still don't know how to create a function. The tutorial I found is putting the menu on the appbar. Which is not relevant.

Here I attach my code.

```
 Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 26,
                width: 26,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1),
                ),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  iconSize: 15,
                  onPressed: () {
                    PopupMenuButton(              // <---- PopUpMenuButton
                      itemBuilder: (context) {},
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your `IconButton` use `PopupMenuButton`, like this:

```
child: PopupMenuButton(
        offset: Offset(0, 40),
        child: Icon(Icons.more_horiz_rounded),
        itemBuilder: (_) => <PopupMenuItem<String>>[
          PopupMenuItem<String>(
              child: Row(
                children: [Icon(Icons.update), Text('update')],
              ),
              value: 'update'),
          PopupMenuItem<String>(
              child: Row(
                children: [Icon(Icons.delete), Text('delete')],
              ),
              value: 'delete'),
        ],
        onSelected: (_) {},
      ),
```

[image]